# Serial type column value getting non-sequential values

Tags: postgresql

I have a serial column created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table_name (
    "_id" serial4 NOT NULL,
```

The assumption I had, is that this column will have only sequential values, i.e. `1, 2, ..., n`, where `n`- is the total number of rows in table `table_name`. However, this is not the case:

```
SELECT max(_id), count(*) FROM public.table_name;
```

yields:

```
959132  111933
```

I know that the assumption I had is most probably an erroneous one, but can you please show me the correct way to achieve what I am after, and preferably also how to update the already non-sequential values to make them sequential.

Postgres version:

```
PostgreSQL 13.2 (Ubuntu 13.2-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Comment: Your assumption is indeed incorrect. But what you are after is also incorrect. The **only** job of a generated primary key value is to be unique. It's completely irrelevant if that value is `1`, `42`, `3673628`, `-363` or something else. Gaps are expected and nothing to worry about. Just move on.

Comment: If a row is deleted from the middle of the table, should all later rows have their _id changed?

Comment: @τεκ there are no deletions in this table, only inserts and upserts.

Comment: When an upsert attempts to insert, it calls [nextval()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-sequence.html) consuming a number from the sequence even if there is a conflict and the row is not inserted.

Comment: It is sequential it is just not gapless. As pointed that is expected as the sequence generator behind `serial` does not rollback when a transaction does, it just moves on.

Answer (score 2):

That is normal. Sequences get gaps if

- you call `nextval()` but don't use the value
- you call `nextval()` and use the value in an `INSERT`, but the transaction fails and is rolled back
- the database crashes
- you created the sequence with `CACHE` greater than 1 and close a database session

People often want a “gap-less sequence”, but most of the time that is not really necessary. You can get that if you use a special counter table that you `UPDATE` whenever you need the next value, but that will serialize all transactions that need a value.

There is no way to get a gap-less sequence without a severe performance impact.

You can find more details in my [article on that topic](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/).